# Zend php generate file in controller then include it

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller

I am working on a Generic Model so  I am trying to generate a php file with the DBTable name then include it in the same ActionController. 
But the page is already loaded and my file could not be included !!

```
$myIniFile = parse_ini_file (MELIS_MODULES_PATH ."/Genericform/application/etc/config.ini",TRUE);
      $this->generateClass("test"); // to create the php file 
     $val="Genericform_Model_".ucfirst($myIniFile["Table"]["name"])."()"; // call it 

    $model = new $val;
```

This  a part of my code.
Do you have any idea please ? 
Thanks

Comment: what is it you need the file for?  maybe we can help you in a way native to Zend Framework?

Comment: Thank you but i found it :). I juste changed the file generation into the _ini() function and then i put the include/ require_once. thx

Comment: This sounds somewhat risky...

Comment: ah ok !, is there another way ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the file generation into the _ini() function and then i put the include/ require_once.